# Writing a pure sql function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I am trying to write a pure SQL function that takes in 2 arguments that correspond to the number of wins and draws a team has earned. Here is the actual definition of the function that I want to write.

> write a pure SQL (i.e. not a PL/pgSQL function) function named calc points total that takes
>        two arguments that correspond to the number of wins and draws earned by a team. This function
>        should return the total number of points earned based on the formula in Equation 1 above.

The equation that I am using for this function is

```
3 · wins + draws
```

I haven't wrote any functions in sql like this before so I looked it up online, but what I found and wrote my code on doesn't look right. Here is the code that I wrote so far, but I don't think it works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_points_total(integer, integer)
RETURN integer AS $$
    SELECT $1 :: ((3 * $1) + $2) AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

The table that I am using for this is

```
Table "lab10.group_standings" 
Column | Type | Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+-----------
team | character varying(25) | not null
wins | smallint | not null
losses | smallint | not null
draws | smallint | not null
points | smallint | not null
Indexes:
"group_standings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team)
Check constraints:
"group_standings_draws_check" CHECK (draws >= 0)
"group_standings_losses_check" CHECK (losses >= 0)
"group_standings_points_check" CHECK (points >= 0)
"group_standings_wins_check" CHECK (wins >= 0)
```

Comment: You need to name the parameters in the function definition.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean? I updated my code does that work?

Comment: @Barmar: No you don't, numbered parameters are just fine, the docs you linked to in your answer even note that the parameter names are optional. The big problem is that `::` is for casting in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @muistooshort He added the numbered parameters after I wrote that. He was using names in the function body, but he didn't have them in the parameter list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax is documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html). It should be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calc_points_total(win INTEGER, draw INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$ SELECT (3 * win) + draw $$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```